# FDs more than 2, more than (stdin/stdout/sterr)

Tags: shell, file-descriptors

I think this post is not off-topic.We had three traditional file descriptors  in Unix contexts:

```
0 == STDIN
1 == STDOUT
2 == STDERR
```

But in new articles, blogs, posts, answers, or so on, I read more than above FDs, For example:
[find out which file descriptors share the same “open file description”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191967/find-out-which-file-descriptors-share-the-same-open-file-description)

[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/)

[I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

[Using exec](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html)

[File descriptors & shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting)

However [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) answered in last link, But after some googling I didn't found a reference about the given FDs.
Also when I use the following hack :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# ls /dev/fd/
0  1  2  3
```

I don't watch more than 4 , But I saw 4 5 or 7 in some examples, I have the following three serious question:

1. What's  `/dev/fd/3`  FD?
2. Where're the rest of them?
3. Do you know a related reference about rest of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you open a file (or anything that you can open like a file, like a socket) you get a file descriptor, which is represented by an int.  The first 3 are automatically created for a process as stdin, stdout and stderr.  Any other files that are opened get other descriptors.  I suspect that it just increments the number each time, but I don't know if that's a reliable phenomenon or not.  So 3 and 4 would be the first 2 files that were opened by the process.  And 7 would be the 5th file opened.

Comment: File handles (that is, the `fd` numbers) are reused.  If you open a file and get the descriptor 3, then close it, then open another file, you will again get the descriptor 3 (even though the descriptor now refers to a different file).  There are some "deep" reasons for that, and some not-so-deep reasons.  The deep reasons involve descriptor inheritance and what happens with daemon processes and the like.  The main not-so-deep reason is that file descriptors available to a process are a finite resource, and you definitely want to avoid leaking them.