# How do I find out what filesystem FUSE is using?

Tags: filesystems, fuse

when I run `mount`, I can see my hard drive mount as `fuseblk`.

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/ecarroll/hd type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

However, `fuseblk` doesn't tell me what filesystem is on my device. I found it using `gparted` but I want to know how to find the fs using the command line utilities.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer provided by in the [comments by Don Crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) to be the best

```
lsblk -no name,fstype
```

This shows me exactly what I want and I don't have to unmount the device,

```
mmcblk0     
└─mmcblk0p1 exfat
```

See also,

- [man page on `lsblk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)

Comment: For this to work you have to be root. Surprisingly (for me) lsblk strips off FS and other infos from its output if you aren't root. This also applies to other solutions proposed below.

Comment: @GianlucaFrustagli I do not have to be root to run `lsblk -no name,fstype` what distro are you using? What are your permissions in /run/udev/data, and /sys?

Comment: I'm using OpenSUSE. FS permissions on /run/udev/data and /sys are:
`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root /run/udev/data/`
`dr-xr-xr-x 12 root root /sys/`

Answer (score 6):

[In general, it is not possible to go from a FUSE mount point to the process implementing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191821/find-what-process-implements-a-fuse-filesystem).

If you know something about how that filesystem works, then it might be possible. You have to track the device side, not the mount point. For example, in your case, the FUSE filesystem is exposing a filesystem on a block device, so you can look for processes that have the blockd device open: [`lsof /dev/sdb1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) or [`fuser /dev/sdb1`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fuser.1.html). Similarly, with SSHFS, you can use `lsof` or `netstat` to look for a process that has a connection to the right server, etc. This gives you a process ID, and `ps` can then tell you what program that process is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `fs` of `/dev/sdb1` through :

`fsck` command:

```
fsck -N /dev/sdb1
```

`mount` command:

```
mount | grep /dev/sdb1
```

`file` command:

```
file -sL /dev/sdb1
```

`df` command:

```
df -T | grep /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: That only works in the special case where the device entry is an actual device, which is rarely the case with FUSE. Furthermore it only reports what the content of the device looks like, which is not always a full indication of which filesystem driver is being used.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to query backing filesystem for any given file is to do

```
lsblk -no name,fstype,mountpoint "$(findmnt --target "$FILE" -no SOURCE)"
```

The output will look something like

```
sdd1 exfat  /media/USER/CARD-A123
```

where `sdd1` is the device name, `exfat` is the underlying filesystem type (e.g. `mount` will show just `fuseblk` for both NFTS and exFat and this will show the real filesystem) and the rest of the output is the mount point for this filesystem.

If you get error such as

```
lsblk: : not a block device
```

the `$FILE` didn't point to readable file or directory.