# How do I determine which filesystem is in use on my "Microsoft basic data" partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-disk, fdisk, partition-table

I'm looking at WD Mybook disk, connected via USB as disk `sde`. Now, `fdisk -l /dev/sde` tells me that the single partition on the drive is:

```
Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1   2048 15628050431 15628048384  7.3T Microsoft basic data
```

but what's that? I don't quite understand what the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_basic_data_partition) is telling me about this partition type. It seems to be auto-mounted fine, and still I don't undestand what filesystem is in use.

Comment: This looks like an effective duplicate of [How do I find out what filesystem FUSE is using?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332712/how-do-i-find-out-what-filesystem-fuse-is-using).

Comment: Parted also shows it. But link to duplicate using lsblk is probably better as with lsblk, you can show many different options. `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Please add a little more information to the question: does "in use" mean "active and mounted" or "I've been told it contains some data, how to access it?" Is this disk fresh from factory, or is it a previously-used mystery box you'll need to figure out? If it's in a factory-default state, I'd place my bets on "either NTFS or exFAT". `file -s /dev/sde1` might yield more clues.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a graphical partition editor like GParted to find out which filesystem is on your partition or you could use the command `lsblk -f`, it should list your filesystem.

Comment: Why do I need the graphics?

Comment: You dont exactly need graphics but I'd say its just an easier way to view your partitions